# Dell Dimension E521 not waking up from sleep or hibernate

Tags: linux, windows, sleep, power-management, suspend

I have been having some unusual power management problems on my Dell Dimension E521. When the computer goes to suspend mode automatically, it suspends properly, but when I turn it on, all I get is a black screen, and the cursor.

When I put the computer to sleep manually, the screen turns black, and nothing happens.

I am having this problem in Windows 7 and 10, and in Ubuntu, Debian, and Fedora. Hiw can I fix this problem?

Comment: Check the bios settings for sleep/suspend.

Comment: @Moab I have checked